# Support several versions of a package if version change breaks code

Tags: python-3.x, module

I have a Python3 project which uses `Biopython` package. One of its modules got removed in the latest version so I have to change a small piece of code to support this change. On the other hand this change would break my code for all "old" version of Biopython (which are heavily used on productive systems).

My questions:

1. What is the proper way to deal with this?
2. If this makes sense: How do I support old and new package versions at the same time? Do I perform a run time check to see which version I have an then run different code? Or is this a bad idea? If you think this is the way to go: Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to ensure a specific version is present is to pin that version in your `requirements.txt` file (or other dependency specifications). There are plenty of systems which rely on legacy versions of packages, and especially for a package without any security implications this is totally reasonable.

If supporting multiple versions is your goal, you could perform some basic checks during your package import process, in an `__init__.py` file or elsewhere. This pattern is somewhat common, especially useful for version compatibility between Python 2 & 3:

```py
def foo_function():
    return

try:
    import biopython.foo as foo
except (ImportError, AttributeError):
    foo = foo_function

foo()
```

I have seen this countless times in the wild on GitHub--of course now that I try to find an example I cannot--but I will update this answer with an example when I do.

**EDIT**: If it's good enough for Numpy, it's probably good enough for the rest of us. [numpy_base.pyi L7-13](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/function_base.pyi#L7)

Comment: `pyi` are not Python modules, strictly speaking

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. Why do you perform the "import biopython" at the first line? Is that necessary?

Comment: Not particularly, originally I was going to use it in `foo_function` but removed that bit. I'll remove it for clarity.